Diffusion of van der waals gas

the problem is diffusion of non-ideal gas
i think, in this situationm the change of internal energy, work, and heat during process is zero because this process is free expansion(diffusion)
but, how can i get internal energy as function of T and V? when i tried $$dU = C_v\Delta T$$
or $$dU=C_p\Delta T$$ but the pressure and volume is not constant. how can i approach this??

Does the partition permit transfer of heat between the chambers.  Is heat allowed to flow through the hole in the partition?

There are no heat exchange through partition. Thank you!

This is a little complicated for a vDW gas.  Would you be able to solve this for an ideal gas?  If yes, let's see.  This will give you some ideas on how to handle VDW gases.

okay i will try ideal gas case. thank you!

See also Internal energy according to the van der Waals equation. Note that "constant-volume heat capacity" is just the name of a material property. When used to calculate the internal energy, it doesn't constrain a process to be at constant volume. I discuss this issue here.
